# Como pudo usar boostrap en handlebars

Tags: html, css, nodejs, express, handlebars.js

Tengo un problema a la hora de usar boostrap, descargue boostrap con npm, estoy usando Handlebars

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la configuración para poder usar boostrap la tengo de la siguiente forma, estoy tratando de hacer pública la dirección donde se encuentra boostrap que se encuentra en node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css

```
//Correr el servidor con npm run dev cuando se este en desarrollo
//Correr el servidor con npm start cuando se vaya a desplegar la aplicacion 
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');


//initializations
const app = express();

//settings
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 4000);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: "main",
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get("views"), "layouts"),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get("views"), "partials"),
    extname: ".hbs",
});
app.engine(".hbs", hbs.engine);
app.set("view engine", ".hbs"); 

//middelwards
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//Global variables 

//Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('index');
});

//Statics files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')))
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')))
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist')))


module.exports = app;
```

Quiero usar los estilos en una archivo con extensión main.hbs de la siguiente forma

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <title>Aria Bit</title>
</head>
<body>

    
    {{{body}}}

    <script src="./js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

El otro archivo que contiene el código html del navbar que quiero cargar, llamado index.hbs

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

La estructura de mi proyecto está de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y me puedan ayudar a resolver esto, y espero que me puedan dar a entender cuál es mi problemática, muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: No, hacer público el directorio de `node_modules` no es el camino. Debes crear una carpeta específica para los archivos estáticos que deseas servir desde tu aplicación Express. Hay 2 formas de hacerlo: mediante la copia manual de los ficheros de Bootstrap dentro de tu carpeta pública, o mediante la creación de un bundle automático usando alguna herramienta que compile tu aplicación, como Webpack.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la recomendación